# Diff between before/after data in Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a method in Cloud Functions to identify all changes in a document triggered by an update in Firestore?

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```js
exports.onUserUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userID}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.data();
    const afterData = change.after.data();
    const changedKeys = diffDocuments(beforeData, afterData);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing provided by the SDK, if that's what you're asking.  You'd have to implement `diffDocuments` on your own.

If you're asking if someone else has implemented something, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" according to the site [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  So that sort of question would need to be asked elsewhere.